# Sql Server Mapping ID's in the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, mapping

I want to produce a map that contains the original room ID and its new room ID equivalent for every room created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the "OUTPUT" clause with your insert statement. You can then map all of the inserted values and the keys that went with it to a different "mapping" table. Edit: I should add, this is all done in a SINGLE transaction, which makes the performance GREAT!

```
Insert Into TableA
(
  Field1,
  Field2,
  Field3
)
  Output Inserted.Field1, Field2, Field3, MappingID
  Into MappingTable
Select Field1, Field2, Field3
From Rooms
```

Here's a link to the msdn site for the OUTPUT clause: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Though I would suggest you to alter the table design and have a separate column each for New and Original site Id, but in present design I think you are looking for following:

```
  SELECT 
    Name, @origSiteID, ControlsSiteNum, ControlsRoomNum, IsActive
  FROM Rooms
  WHERE SiteID = @newSiteID
```